# SQL query data different in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a SQL query that when I load into PQ untouched is showing different results then what SSMS is showing. Is there a setting or something simple causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: As posted, it is not possible to answer your question. What exactly is different? The number of rows? The number of columns? The order? Please edit your question and add more detail about the difference.

Comment: Also you can show your query and how you are loading in PQ.

Comment: That might mean your datatypes are not  set right -- showing any errors, or records that are different would help.